# Trigger a field Update after email is sent

Tags: apex, email, field-update, email-alert

I'm inserting records in to a custom object from apex and sending an email through workflow email alert, However whenever a update has been performed on the custom object I want to trigger the second email for the same inserted records. I'm planning to create a checkbox and update the field on the record after email is sent so that I can use the checkbox to trigger the email again on update. But I don't see a way to know if the email has already been sent.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When using Enhanced Email, sending an email is a triggerable event, but there are some considerations. See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm&type=5 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

An email send is not a "triggerable" action, so the only way you can set your checkbox field is in your before insert trigger (or as a second item in your workflow rule).  You have to assume that the first email was sent.